# Customize active tab with jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, customization

I'm trying to modify the script of the vertical tabs on this page http://www.bluimage.it/dev/ to put an arrow on the right of the tab as I can show the active/selected one. I try to call a css class as shown (note "case "left:"):

```
    function showContentDesc(modid, ind, pos)
{
        i = 0;
        switch(pos)
        {
            case "top":
                thisstyle=document.getElementById("menu_" + modid + "_" + ind).style.borderBottom;
                while (document.getElementById("content_" + modid + "_" + i) != null) {
                    document.getElementById("content_" + modid + "_" + i).style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("menu_" + modid + "_" + i).style.borderBottom = thisstyle;
                    i++;
                }
                document.getElementById("menu_" + modid + "_" + ind).style.borderBottom = "none";
                break;
            case "bottom":
                thisstyle=document.getElementById("menu_" + modid + "_" + ind).style.borderTop;
                while (document.getElementById("content_" + modid + "_" + i) != null) {
                    document.getElementById("content_" + modid + "_" + i).style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("menu_" + modid + "_" + i).style.borderTop = thisstyle;
                    i++;
                }
                document.getElementById("menu_" + modid + "_" + ind).style.borderTop = "none";
                break;
            case "right":
                thisstyle=document.getElementById("menu_" + modid + "_" + ind).style.borderLeft;
                while (document.getElementById("content_" + modid + "_" + i) != null) {
                    document.getElementById("content_" + modid + "_" + i).style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("menu_" + modid + "_" + i).style.borderLeft = thisstyle;
                    i++;
                }
                document.getElementById("menu_" + modid + "_" + ind).style.borderLeft = "none";
                break;
            case "left":
            default:
                thisstyle=document.getElementById("menu_" + modid + "_" + ind).style.borderRight;
                while (document.getElementById("content_" + modid + "_" + i) != null) {
                    document.getElementById("content_" + modid + "_" + i).style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("menu_" + modid + "_" + i).style.borderRight = thisstyle;
                    i++;
                }
                document.getElementById("menu_" + modid + "_" + ind).className = "sliptabs-left-menuitem-container-active";
                break;
        }
        document.getElementById("content_" + modid + "_" + ind).style.display = "inline";
}
```

...and it works, but when i go to other tabs the selected in past tab remain actived! how can I deactivate the other ones and set the active only in that in which I am?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at simplified snippet [**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/itezox/8/edit).

I used jQuery as you included a jQuery tag.

```
$("ul.menu li").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".selected").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Every menu item will get a click handler that will check for sibling with class "selected" and remove this class. After that he will set the class to "selected" of the current menu item.

Comment: Why not just removeClass() and addClass() the class?

$("ul.menu li").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings("selected").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});

also $("li.selected") would affect other menues as well.

Comment: Thanks dzejkej and Stefan! I try to put that script in my own and change "ul.menu li" with "ul.mymenuclass li" but still don't work...maybe i did not understand where i have to put it??
I put your script after "break;"...is it wrong? sorry but i'm a newbie!

Comment: @Andrea: Make sure your page have jQuery available. My example code should be executed only once and after page is rendered. You can put in your js file or inside the body element and use `$(function() { /** PUT IT HERE */ });` so it will get executed when document is ready (see [this](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)).

Comment: @Andrea: In case you stil have trouble then use [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com) or [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net), put relevant parts there (html, js) and try to comment your code.

Comment: ok guys! i tried so many times but still remain the same problem! anyway i solve with a combination of css and js trick.
really thanks for the attention/patience!